# How to change php folder for Windows on EasyPHP?

Tags: php, laravel, easyphp

I am using easyPHP as a local server. I was using php version 5.6... now I want to install Laravel 5.5.0 by using windows command line via composer. Though I changed php version from 5.6.. to 7.0 from easyPHP admin panel, composer still trying to install Laravael by using php.ini file of version 5.6.. I mean composer still thinks I use php 5.6.. how can I change default php folder for composer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change PHP version, change it in Environment variables (edit "PATH", chnage php path to php7 path)